# Взаимноутопающим

Tags: словообразование

Правильно ли образовано это слово? Например, если говорить о направленных друг на друга зеркалах, либо глазах, которые, как бы утопают в глубине друг друга? Или что-то с этим словом не так? Может, оно должно писаться раздельно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, и в слове "образованно".

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобные слова образуются с начальной частью "взаимо-" (взаимоисключающие, взамодействующие и т.п.). В возможности взаимного утопания (взаимоутопания) не уверен: обычно утопающее становится жертвой той среды, в которой утопает.

Взаимоутопающие (прил.) - гипотетическое совместное свойство глаз, погруженных один в другой и от этого пребывающих в состоянии взаимной утопленности. (Аналогичный пример из реально употребляемого: взаимопроникающие поля и среды.)

Взаимно утопающие (наречие + причастие несов. вида) - глаза, участвующие в продолжающемся действии взаимного утопания одного в другом.

Answer (score 1):

Разве что окказионализм.